# AWS Lambda's indirect S3 requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-lambda

I noticed AWS Lambda causes S3 tier 1 and 2 requests. Do these cost anything after 12 months free tier expires?

Specifically:

- Create new AWS Lambda function in AWS console causes 1 tier 1 S3 request

  - `Amazon Simple Storage Service Requests-Tier1: $x per request - PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST requests: 1 Request`
- Delete AWS Lambda function in AWS console causes 1 tier 2 S3 request

  - `Amazon Simple Storage Service Requests-Tier1: $x per request - GET and all other requests: 1 Request`

I am not using AWS S3 (no buckets in all regions).

You can try creating or deleting an AWS Lambda function, then check `https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home` (expand details: `Simple Storage Service > Region > Tier 1 and Tier 2 requests`) after a day when it has been updated.

Is this a bug or have I missed something in their overly complex pricing scheme?